# Know the position of a query with ActiveRecord (RoR) after filtering for a ranking table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using Rails with ActiveRecord.

I am doing a game which after playing you can submit the total score to your database.
The problem comes when you need to create a ranking page. What the ranking page should display is the best 20 users with highest score in descending order. After getting all the data (and process it if necessary after getting from the DB), I just send it via AJAX. I am using AngularJS to make an HTTP Ajax Request. Although this is a another story.

I'll send the information in JSON format being an Array with each index a Hash. Still there are some things I don't know how to do them neatly. I have to:

1. Know if the currently logged in user is among the 20 bests users and mark it with color or something so when it gets to the client, the client can color it.
2. If the user is not among the 20 bests users go search it and get the ranking position. IN SHORT: I don't know how to get the ranking of an specific user.

I have the next model:

> **GameSession (Model):**
>
> - id:integer
> - id_user:integer
> - score:integer

---

**Solution to problem 1**

> - First I get the 20 bests Records. I iterate each of them and I compare if the ID of each record is the same of the current logged in user ID. If this condition is accomplished, then we know it is among the 20 best users. If the user weren't in there, I would look for his highest score record and push it to the JSON array I will send the user.

**Solution to problem 2:**

> - I have to make a query to search the user with WHERE by user_Id. What I'll do is to get the highest score of all the times the user played the game (I register all the games the user does). After that I would apply probably apply a DISTINCT on the "user_id", order it by score DESC, and get the row index of the resultant table after performing the query. I don't know if there's a way to know the index of a row of the table you get after making a query.

I don't know if I am over complicating things too much or I am not using a good approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hypothetical question: How would you determine the rank if multiple users had the same score?

Comment: Good question. I wouldn't really care that much which would be the first one in that case but we could decide on the one who's got the oldest submit date. Still if this complicates things, then I wouldn't care too much about it. I am looking for the easiest solution (which does not mean it will be a complex or straightforward answer). Nonetheless I am open to anyway of resolving it, or suggestions to improve some design issues I didn't take into account as you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint: count the number of users who have a best score greater than the current user's best score. Add 1 to that count, and that gets you the current user's rank.

For the sake of efficiency, consider storing each user's best score with the user record and updating it whenever a user finishes a game session. Add an index to the `best_score` column on the `users` table so that you can do the count quickly.

To generate the leader board, just sort users by their best score and limit to the top 20.

Some code:

```
 class User
   def rank
     User.where("best_score > ?", best_score).count + 1
   end

   def self.leaders
     order("best_score desc, id asc").limit(20)
   end
 end
```

Then you can write:

```
 current_user.rank  # returns ranking of user as an integer
 User.leaders       # returns a list of 20 top scorers, highest scorer first
```

To know whether the current user is in the top 20, you can just check

```
if current_user.rank <= 20
```

I see above that there was some discussion about how to handle cases where two or more users have the same score. The code above generates identical ranking numbers for same-score users, so if the 2nd and 3rd users have the same score, your rankings may look like 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6. I think this is a common way to handle it.

To help ensure stable ordering, I added `order id asc` so that when two or more users have the same score, the *older* user (the one with the lower user id) will be listed first.

One final bit: when you do the migration to add `best_score` to your `users` table, set `default: 0` and `allow_nil: false` so that you don't get into trouble with users who have played no games. Either that, or adjust the `rank` function so that it does something reasonable (like return `nil` or `MAXINT`) for users who haven't played any games and thus have no `best_score`.

Comment: Many thanks! This works wonderfully and your tips are very helpful to me. Plus it is a neat and easy solution to implement. It's been 1 month since I started using Ruby on Rails and any input proves to be helpful to me. The last details you added to the end are insightful. Probably if you hadn't told me the last paragraph I would have just update all the tables and put something like 0. Still I can put a rake task to take care of putting later on the current best_score to user.

Thanks for your time!